# How would I add iAd to viewcontroller Over all views

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I have a application that switches between multiple views in a view controller in storyboard. I want to display an ad over all the views in the application. what is the correct method of doing this? Thanks

Comment: The only correct way is in a manner that meets your requirements.  It sounds like your AD view will need to reside in a common view within your app, which may be your root controller's view.

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you are going to change your entire view hierarchy, you should have a separate view controller. That will just give better encapsulation. If you have two or more completely separate view hierarchies managed by the same view controller, then your view controller code is going to have two or more mostly unconnected sections. You could build an entire program in one class if you want, but it isn't good object-oriented programming.

If you really want to keep one view controller, I'd recommend making a top-level view which contains your current content view and your ad view. The content view should be a bit smaller than the screen, so that it doesn't cover the ad view. Then to switch to the second view, you only replace the content view child of the top-level view. You don't change the ad's position in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The normal approach is to keep a reference to the `AdBannerView` in your `AppDelegate` and every time you change view controller, move it to somewhere on that view. Since you have only one view controller, you should move it to the appropriate view whenever you switch. Suitable code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499703/how-to-create-a-global-reference-for-iad-and-implement-in-multiple-viewcontrolle).

Comment: to clarify, I got it to display the ad on the first view by adding it as a subview. When I remove the ad from the first view and add it to the second view, it give off a "ADBannerView must be part of a view hierarchy managed by a UIViewController" error.

Comment: Then it might work if you first add the second view to the view hierarchy, e.g. making it the root view of the view controller, and then add the ad to it.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are supposed to re-create the ad in each view controller. iAd has some fairly strict policies about how you must show the ad.

Comment: I only use one view controller with multiple views. I can only get the iad to appear on the first view in the view controller. I want to keep the ad on top of all the views in the view controller.